# A word for what I thought collimate meant

Tags: single-word-requests

I incorrectly used the word 'collimate' to describe the formation of columns. In reality the word shares no root with column. Is there a word that describes the formation of columns or rows or lines of objects?

In short, is there a word for what I thought collimate meant?

Comment: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/columnize

Comment: I saw that, it seems to be used exclusively for text formatting. I guess there is nothing keeping me from using it in other ways.

Comment: In military terms you could use "form up".

Comment: Form up into columns works well.

Comment: arrange in columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word you meant to use was "columnize." Collimate is typically used in the context of light rays and optics.

[Definition of Columnize](http://www.yourdictionary.com/columnize)

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer. I am aware of that word but it is used exclusively to explain columns as in text. I don't care though, people will understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone with ***align***. It is not limited to any particular type of thing, and can be used to mean *line things up in rows or columns*. Attested by *Oxford Thesaurus of English* and other Oxford publications. Example given:

> Desks are typically **aligned** in straight rows facing forwards.